# passing parameters to a user defined function

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I created a user defined function with 3 parameters. While calling the function if I happen to hardcode the value as indicated in the line which is commented everything works well but if I try to make use of parameters I am getting the following error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data$X == "Key1", , value = list(X = integer(0),  :
  provided 17 variables to replace 16 variables
```

The data frame data contains 16 columns !!!

code used :

```
Change <- function('Arc', Value, 'Key1'){

  data<-read.csv("matrix.csv")

  #This statement works but the below does not ......   
  #data[data$'X'=='C1',]$'OGB_OGB' <-(data[data$'X'=='C1',]$'OGB_OGB' / Value)  

  data[data$'X'=="Key1",]$"Arc" <-data[data$'X'=="Key1",]$"Arc" / Value     
  return(data)
}

tes<-Change("OGB_OGB",.3,"C1")
```

I am guessing somewhere i am messing up the strings parameters..please help

Comment: I'm very suprised your defintion of the function did not return an error along the lines `unexpected string constant in Change <- function('Arc'`

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a function

```
  foo <- function('a') {'a'}
```

This will return the error

> foo <- function('a'

So you aren't even creating a function.

When creating a function using `function`, you must pass it an list of named arguments,

ie. something like `foo <- function(a){}` or `foo <- function(a = 1){}` if you want to give it a "default" value.

Within the function you refer to the arguments using `names` (`symbols` not `character strings`)

You have also got a great example fortune(312)

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(312)
```

> The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical
>   shortcut and like any other magic if used incorrectly is
>   likely to do the programmatic equivalent of turning
>   yourself into a toad.
>      -- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to
>         access a column whose name is stored in y via x$y
>         rather than x[[y]])
>         R-help (February 2012)

Therefore your function could be something like

```
Change <- function(Arc,Value, key = 'Key1') {

data<-read.csv("matrix.csv")
# calculate the logical vector only once 
# slightly more efficient
index <- data[['X']]==key
# you might consider  index <- data[['X']] %in% key
# if you wanted more than one value in `key`
# replace as appropriate
data[[Arc]][index] <- data[[Arc]][index] / Value
# return the data
return(data)
}


tes<-Change(Arc = "OGB_OGB",Value = .3,key = "C1")
```

Comment: You must have `fortune(312)` on speed dial.

Comment: Thank u so much.....Change <- function('Arc', Value, 'Key1') was a typo ..i intended to put Change <- function(Arc, Value, Key1)